HOW TO BLOCK CONTRACT CALL BUT ALLOWING SMART WALLET 4337
I have contracts on Arbitrum. I don't want contract call to my contract since it is easily get hacked. But I do want have account abstraction which I have to allow Smart Account call to my contract.
Is there anyway to sort this out? Thank you


I don't want contract call to my contract since it is easily get hacked.

This is not possible.
If your contract can easily get hacked, I suggest adding whitelist based owner or access control.
